# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I've got a rails application on DigitalOcean. I'm using the Comfortable Mexican Sofa CMS. I added the gem and ran `rails generate comfy:cms` and `rake db:migrate` but when I navigate to example.com/admin, I get a 500 error and my application isn't able to find the necessary tables. Here's the error I get in the logs.

```
I, [2014-06-24T21:51:18.397255 #18789]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 173.10.20.190 at 2014-06-24 21:51:18 +0000

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:18.425183 #18789]  INFO -- : Processing by HomeController#index as HTML

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:18.442366 #18789]  INFO -- :   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:18.445116 #18789]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 9.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:18.599085 #18786]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/rails.png" for 173.10.20.190 at 2014-06-24 21:51:18 +0000

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:23.516755 #18789]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin" for 173.10.20.190 at 2014-06-24 21:51:23 +0000

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:23.522184 #18789]  INFO -- : Processing by Comfy::Admin::Cms::BaseController#jump as HTML

I, [2014-06-24T21:51:23.526053 #18789]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

F, [2014-06-24T21:51:23.532357 #18789] FATAL -- :

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'comfy_cms_sites'):
```

What seems strange to me is that when I run `rails c` and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`, the tables show up and 'comfy_cms_sites' is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've run your migrations on your production db with

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```